# SQL clause to find certain pairs in a select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, conditional-statements

So I've run a SELECT which gave me this result so far:
[image: My select result]

These two columns are from different tables I've joined together. Both are stored as Numbers. In this case "ID" is the main entity and ID_1 describes a state that "ID" can be in. A main entity can have multiple states at once and multiple entities can be in the same state at the same time.

Right now, my select shows ALL entity-state-pairs on my DB. My goal for the final result is to show the rows for any entity that does not have at least one entry with their state set to 1 or 9. In the above example, I would like the final results to show the rows with the following IDs: 62 and 82

Any idea on how to archive this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, it's quite impossible to answer without knowing your table structure.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query which produced the results shown above. Thanks.

Comment: `GROUP BY table1.id HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN table2.id IN (1,9) THEN 1 END ) = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the ID's from the second table where `ID_1` is 1 or 9:

```
SELECT ID
FROM second_table
WHERE ID_1 IN (1, 9)
```

Using that, you can select from the first table where the ID isn't in the result set above:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
  FROM first_table
  WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM second_table
    WHERE ID_1 IN (1, 9)
  );
```

If you have a scenario where, for example, ID 63 has three records in the second table with `ID_1` values of 3, 4 and 6, the `SELECT DISTINCT` will make sure ID 63 only shows once in the results instead of three times.

**Addendum**

Also see the answer from Bob Jarvis. The query is more involved but returns the same results. More importantly, it will run a lot faster for larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an outer join to accomplish this by doing something akin to

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
  FROM TABLE_1 ti
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t2.ID
                     FROM TABLE_2 t2
                     WHERE t2.ID_1 IN (1, 9))
  WHERE t2.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: +1. I considered something like this as a second option in my answer, but given the OP seemed shaky with Oracle I was afraid of overload. I'm glad you added this alternative; it's almost always faster than the `NOT IN` version.